# classic asp insert multiple selected records from drop down list and insert into database

Tags: database, asp-classic

I have a multiple drop down list populated from database. How do I insert the selected records into database? I am using Classic ASP. Here is my `addstudent.asp` file...

```vbs
<select name="myic" id="myic" multiple="multiple">
    <%While (NOT listall.EOF)%>
        <option value="<%=(listall.Fields.Item("ICNO").Value)%>">
            <%=(listall.Fields.Item("Class").Value)%>-<%=(listall.Fields.Item("StudentName").Value)%>
        </option>
        <%listall.MoveNext()
    Wend
    If (listall.CursorType > 0) Then
        listall.MoveFirst
    Else
        listall.Requery
    End If%>
```

Comment: Have you closed off your `<select>` tag with a matching `</select>`?

Comment: You will have to get the form data and do multiple inserts to your DB. That depends on the DBMS, if you GET or POST your Form, etc. You should break down your question into separate problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post the form to another script (or the same page if you like) using a form with an action set to the url of the receiving script.

```
form method="post" action="[your script url]"
```

Grab the field value using:

```
myic = Request.Form("myic")
```

From memory this will be a comma separated string as its coming from a multiple select. So split the string to get all the values:

```
MyArray=Split(myic,",")
```

Then iterate through the array to store the values in the database

```
For i=0 To UBound(MyArray)

myVal=Trim(MyArray(i))

[send myVal to the db]

Next
```

Note the use of trim as the csv string can also contain spaces.